# how to add more data to each node of bazel query

Tags: bazel, bazel-query

I wanted to see all of my dependency graph for a bazel target, for that I can use below query

```
bazelisk query --notool_deps --noimplicit_deps "deps(//sample-target:sample-target)" --output graph
```

this will show me the dependency graph,

now I wanted to show more data on each node, for example if a node/target has attribute tags I wanted to show all tags there

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by tag can be done with the `attr()` function:

https://bazel.build/query/language#attr

But I don't think there's a direct way to print all the tags. A way around this is to use another output format like `--output=streamed_jsonproto` which will include the attributes of the targets among other things.

For example:

```
genrule(
  name = "gen",
  outs = ["gen.txt"],
  cmd = "touch $@",
  tags = ["foo", "bar"],
)
```

`bazel query --notool_deps --noimplicit_deps "gen" --output=streamed_jsonproto` will include:

```
{
  "type": "RULE",
  "rule": {
    "name": "//:gen",
    "ruleClass": "genrule",
    "attribute": [
      ...
      {
        "name": "tags",
        "type": "STRING_LIST",
        "stringListValue": [
          "bar",
          "foo"
        ],
        "explicitlySpecified": true,
        "nodep": false
      },
      ...
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

Or if you feel like getting into it, the code to generate the graph output is here and it might not be too difficult to have it add the tags to the node text:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/3713606de9aa5d85f71cc07d466b911d79024183/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/query2/query/output/GraphOutputWriter.java#L167